# android mediaplayer with api url

Tags: android, laravel, api

I am trying to run media through android mediaplayer with some API link (thus doesn't have .mp3 in the end of url) as follows:

android code :

```
headers.put("token", token_value);
myPlayer.setDataSource(
                    getApplicationContext(),
                    Uri.parse(url),//url : http://basedomain.com/api/getmp3
                    headers
            );
```

backend laravel code :

```
$song_path = "abc.mp3";   
$path = storage_path().DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR."somefolder".DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$song_path;
$response = new BinaryFileResponse($path);
return $response;
```

I am getting the binary response from laravel code(tested through postman), however android code is not playing the music from laravel response.

android issue list :

1) W/MediaPlayer: Couldn't open http://basedomain.com/api/getmp3: java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider: http://basedomain.com/api/getmp3

2) E/MediaPlayer: error (1, -2147483648)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the reason behind this issue. My backend laravel api call was a POST request. Changing the same to Get request worked for me.
Also changing request from POST to GET was not an issue as my request parameters were sent through the header. (This was done because android mediaplayer's setDataSource method only accepts headers and not body parameters).

In short android mediaplayer is expecting us to use GET request only.

Answer (score 0):

I've just tried the following code in Android studio targeting Android SDK 28 and it works fine. Make sure your API is actually returning the mp3 file.

[Android MediaPlayer  docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer)

```
    try {
        MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();
        player.setDataSource("https://yourdomain/yourmusic.mp3");
        player.prepare();
        player.start();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try testing your code using a url to a known public mp3 file to verify that the MediaPlayer code is correct.  Once that is working, you can narrow the issue down to either the token not being set correctly or your server not returning the mp3 file correctly.  Maybe the response doesn't indicate it is an mp3 file correctly and thus the media player doesn't know how to handle it.

Comment: I tried with an mp3 URL, its working fine. This means the mediaplayer part is working perfectly. However, as shown in laravel code my api is returning binary response(laravel BinaryFileResponse). I am not sure whether mediaplayer can handle it . 
I want somewhat similar to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37548096/serve-mp3-stream-for-android-with-laravel)
so what changes i need to make so that mediaplayer handles the binary response?

Comment: Here's another post that suggests a fix for the server BinaryFileResponse. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43558919/serve-mp3-file-from-laravel-for-ios-avplayer

Comment: Even after following the link i.e adding headers with the mime type, etc, I am getting the same binary response. I guess that's the intended behaviour of how data is transferred. I did a curl request and dumped the binary data into some test.mp3 file. The test.mp3 looks good.
So the problem remains the same, android mediaplayer is unable to recognize the binary data.

Comment: It would be great if anyone could dig into this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37548096/serve-mp3-stream-for-android-with-laravel/38037279#38037279) post and ask about the android part implemetation or ask the owner of it to look into my question. I don't have enough reputation to comment on others post